# Taylor series expansion of $\frac{(1- \cos x)}{x^2} $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

According to my calculations, the Taylor series expansion for $1- \cos x$ around $x=\pi$ is 
$$2 - \frac{(x-\pi)^2}{2} + \frac{(x-\pi)^4}{24} - \frac{(x-\pi)^6}{720} + \frac{(x-\pi)^8}{40320} -\dotsb
$$

In solving the Taylor series expansion of $\frac{(1- \cos x)}{x^2}$ around $x= \pi$, would it be the same if I'll just multiply $\frac{1}{x^2}$ to the series written above? If that's not possible, how can I solve the series expansion of the quotient of two functions without doing ridiculously long sessions of product rule differentiation?

Comment: No, dividing by $x^2$ won't give you the Taylor expansion around $\pi$ (contrary to what some posts announce). The denominator is $((x-\pi)+\pi)^2$. If you prefer, you are developing $(1-\cos(t+\pi))/(t+\pi)^2$ around $t=0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As $x \to \pi$, you may express $\dfrac1{x^2}$ as 
$$
\begin{align}
\dfrac1{x^2}&=\dfrac1{(\pi+\color{red}{x-\pi})^2}
\\\\&=\dfrac1{\pi^2} \cdot \dfrac1{\left(1+\frac{\color{red}{x-\pi}}\pi\right)^2}
\\\\&=\dfrac1{\pi^2} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{\pi^n}\left({\color{red}{x-\pi}}\right)^n
\end{align}
$$ then multiplying by
$$
1-\cos x=2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\left({\color{red}{x-\pi}}\right)^{2n}
$$ one gets, as $x \to \pi$,

> $$
> \dfrac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{2}{\pi^2}-\frac{4 (x-\pi)}{\pi^3}+\left(\frac{6}{\pi^4}-\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\right) (x-\pi)^2-\left(\frac{8}{\pi^5}-\frac{1}{\pi^3}\right) (x-\pi)^3+\cdots.
> $$

Comment: Fancy way to rewrite $x^{-2}$. Really simplifies calculating the series by hand from the definition of Taylor Series! A +1 from me for sure.

Comment: @Yves Daoust what can you say about this solution?

Comment: @Wilhelm: that I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're totally fine to multiply by $1/x^2$. You need to be a little careful, as this changes the radius of convergence, but that is the best way to find the taylor polynomial that you are after.

**Edit:** This is not the *only* thing you should do, as Taylor Polynomials have non-negative exponents only. However, some algebraic manipulation can be preformed after multiplying by $1/x^2$ (as shown in another answer) and *that* gives the solution. I took the OP to be asking f such manipulation is logically valid (which it is) and not if that's all you have to do to get the taylor polynomial (which it isn't).

Comment: Are you sure?  See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Taylor+series+%281-cos+x%29%2Fx^2+at+x%3Dpi

Comment: @Emilio Novati Its over $x^2$ in the question and yours is over $x$

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Notice the whole link isn't clickable. A better link would be http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B(1+-+Cos%5Bx%5D)%2Fx%5E2,+%7Bx,+Pi,+4%7D%5D

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen I can see the entire link. Its clickable. Note that its Emilio's comment and not mine :)

Comment: @EmilioNovati I would think the two should both have the same coefficient of $x^n$ by the uniqueness of series expansions. Notice that we can write the OP's function as $\frac{1}{x^2}\left(1-\cos x \right)$ and then apply the series only to the inside of the brackets, multiplying by $x^{-2}$ afterward.

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Oh, I know. I was simply saying that the end of the link reads "^2+‌​at+x%3Dpi", which was cut off from the clickable part. Emilio's link DOES divide by $x^2$, he just pasted the link incorrectly

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand why the link is not complete.

Comment: You are totally not fine to multiply by $1/x^2$. This yields a series the first term of which is $2/x^2$. I wouldn't call that Taylor.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You have to do some algebra afterwards, as shown in Oliver's answer, but I had interpreted the OP as asking if dividing by $x^2$ was a valid step to take. It is a valid step to take and the one the OP should do next. Then the OP should reorganize the sum as Oliver showed

Comment: No, the development is requested to be around $x=\pi$. You are actually dividing by $((x-\pi)+\pi)^2$ and no simplification is possible. You must inform the OP that merely dividing by $x^2$ is not the thing to do. You said something in the Edit, but not enough for an answer.